# SmtpClient.SendMailAsync randomly gives asynchronous operation error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, webforms

A problem has recently started occurring on our older ASP.NET webforms application.

Seemingly randomly, our calls to `SmtpClient.sendMailAsync` are throwing the SmtpException with this message:

> An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle.
> If this exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is marked <%@ Page Async="true" %>. This exception may also indicate an attempt to call an "async void" method, which is generally unsupported within ASP.NET request processing. Instead, the asynchronous method should return a Task, and the caller should await it

I understand what the error message means, however none of it applies. All of the calls to `sendMailAsync` are called in purely `async` functions starting with:

```
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem
```

For example:

```
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(async () => {
    smtpClient = new SmtpClient(smtpSection.Host, smtpSection.Port);
    smtpClient.Timeout = 10000; // don't block too long.
    smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(smtpSection.Username, smtpSection.Password);
    smtpClient.EnableSsl = smtpSection.UseSsl;

    ...
    await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(mail);
});
```

Using `ContinueAwait(false)` does not address the problem. Neither does setting

```
SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(null);
```

at the beginning of the `async` function.

The error almost never occurs during debugging or on our staging, only in production, and it seems to happen much more frequently under heavier load. To me, this indicates a problem with the thread used to service the background task. Assuming it was getting a thread that still had a UI synchronization context, I added the `SetSynchronizationContext(null)` but to no avail.

Apparently, `sendMailAsync` has some code in it to check for a potential deadlock, but it it isn't based on the synchronization context, I can't tell what that check is doing.

Looking at the code for  `QueueBackgroundWorkItem`, I don't think `Task.run` would necessarily behave differently, other than potentially get aborted when the app recycles. Both pull from the thread pool.

Does anybody know what could be going on? There are hundreds of other endpoints, both WebAPI 2.0 and [WebMethod] type (static methods for ajax calls in the pages), and this problem became a lot more prevalent when we started switching over to WebAPI, but only actually shows up in when we use `QueueBackgroundWorkItem` from a [WebMethod], not in any stuff we've switched over.

**EDIT**: the text of the error message indicates it is generated by ASP.NET classes and only path I see to that is, in fact, the `SynchronizationContext`. Although, how it gets wrapped as an `SmtpException`, I am not sure, since the `SmtpClient` source code does not seem to be doing that. (EDIT: ahh, we are getting text from inner exception: `SmtpException` is just a "fail", and it wraps any inner exception with `SmtpException`)

**EDIT**
I've concluded this has to do with `ConfigureAwait(false)`
Although my context starts out without any SynchronizationContext, the use of `ConfigureAwait(false)` at some point before calling `sendMailAsync` results in a switch to a new context. I could explicitly clear it after each ConfigureAwait and may try that. `sendMailAsync` doesn't seem to care if I use `configureAwait` but will see what happens.

**EDIT**
Apparently, SynchronizationContext doesn't actually flow across `await`. This is surprising, considering the number of sources that imply it does, but the ExecutionContext sometimes flows it, and sometimes does not.
See this blog:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/executioncontext-vs-synchronizationcontext/

This basically says that mscorlib uses ExecutionContext differently than anything else, by using internal methods that prevent flowing SynchroniztionContext.
Anything else that uses `ExecutionContext.Capture` will actually capture the SynchronizationContext as well, and that will flow to other threads started with `Task.Run`, at least if they capture any context from the caller. Thus, it restores a SynchronizationContext that really doesn't belong in the new thread. All tests I've done have this being very random and unpredictable.

This is also only under .NET Framework.  .NET 7 and later seem to work just fine.

Comment: If it seems to be happening under load, then I would seriously consider moving the mail sending into an external service and using a message bus of some sort to trigger the mails. It's safer in the long run, much more maintainable and far better than using `QueueBackgroundWorkItem`

Comment: Also worth noting that if IIS recycles your app pool, any tasks queued up with `QueueBackgroundWorkItem` will get stopped.

Comment: The queued tasks get cancelled, followed by a timeout period for them to complete/cancel, versus being immediately stopped when using `Task.run`

Comment: for most cases, we do actually offload to an external process, but there are a lot of these one off cases (single email to single user), and the problem is perplexing.

Comment: by under load, it isn't a lot of email going out, just a lot more activity in general, so a lot more threads are being used and returned to pool rapidly, versus on staging or debug where mostly 1 thread is used.

Comment: May I ask, because you haven't mentioned it: did you actually tried to satisfy the constraints of the exception message? For example, is your Page.Async set to TRUE? I guess you did because of the sporadic nature of the error. The information was not provided so I felt the need to ask this.

Comment: The only SmtpException thrown by the client is the SmtpFailedRecipientException. In this case the issue could be related to the endpoint. You may want to catch the exception and enqueue the job for a retry (e.g. use a retry counter before dropping the job).

Comment: Page.Async should only be relevant "while executing a Page". The reason we use QueueBackgroundWorkItem is so we will no longer be executing a page

Comment: *"Asynchronous operations may only be started within an __asynchronous__ handler or module"* - The complete context must be async too. For example, the controller.

Comment: @BionicCode well that's not true. I believe it is line 690 in the `SmtpClient.SendAsync` method where it wraps any exception as SmtpException, but there are several other cases (timeout, for example)

Comment: @BionicCode well, the controller does seem to be interfering, although the point of QueueBackgroundWorkItem is to use a new thread from the thread pool and change the context so it is not within the controller. And the mechanism checked is the SynchronizationContext, right?

Comment: You should declare the controller's entry point as async otherwise the SmtpClient won't be happy. I have not checked the internals of the QBWI type but it's likely that it doesn't provide it's own async context root. This context is usually is provided by the call at the root of the call stack. According to the error message this is not irrrelvant. At least you should try and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: *"ahh, we are getting text from innerexception. SmtpException is just a "fail", and it wraps any inner exception with SmtpException"* - Then what is the inner exception saying? What type is it?

Comment: @BionicCode yes, worth a shot, at least to get more information. The controller and page do not appear in the call stack, of course.

Comment: That IS the text from the inner exception, but I don't have the inner exception type. Need to add that to the logging then need to get it into production.

Answer (score 0):

I have confirmed the issue is with the `await` and/or `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Simplified reproducible case is like this:

```
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(async () => {
    Log(SyncrhonizationContext.Current?.GetType()?.Name);
    var mail = await LoadMailMessage();
 
    ...
    Log(SyncrhonizationContext.Current?.GetType()?.Name);
    await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(mail);
});
```

The SynchronizatinoContext SOMETIMES changes from "null" to "AspNetSychronizationContext" after the first await (possibly only if using `ConfigureAwait(false)`. I haven't been able to ensure this is not set deep in call tree). The `LoadMailMessage` is just doing a database read and the library does not appear to set SyncCtx (based on search of source code).
If SynchonizationContext is null, then doing an `await` uses the ExecutionContext defaults for Task, which in the ASP.net process is apparently AspNetSynchronizationContext. This may just be luck of the draw in terms of which thread is pulled from the pool, and what it was used for previously.

Using `ConfigureAwait(false)` definitely does not help. Without setting that, one could set a new SynchronizationContext, and preserve it, but if using `ConfigureAwait(false)`, the context will sometimes change.

This seems to violate a lot of information out there which presumes as long as you actually do asynchronous work for the first `ConfigureAwait` call, you do not need to do it afterwards.

And, interestingly, using `ConfigureAwait(false)` on SendMailAsync doesn't help. The `OperationStart` is being called on the context regardless of ConfigureAwait, so the AspNetSynchronizationContext is throwing the exception anyway.

Note: Cannot reproduce with `Task.delay` so perhaps is related to the MysqlConnector.net library.

Solutions seem to be:

- run in a process where nothing ever sets a SynchronizationContext (is possible with ASP.net core)
- Set a default SynchronizationContext and don't use ConfigureAwait anywhere [NOT ABLE TO VERIFY]
- always set SynchronizationContext to null after using ConfigureAwait (Confirmed it works but - seriously?)

Comment: QBWI and the SyncCtx shouldn't be behaving like this. Please ensure you have [set `httpRuntime.targetFramework` to at least 4.5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework/) *and* are running at least 4.5 on your production servers. I'd also check for any code explicitly setting the SyncCtx in your entire app.

Comment: `Task.Run` has the same behavior,  and we require 4.7 or higher to run.
`<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />`

Comment: 4.8.04161 is installed.

Comment: The only thing I can find expliciting setting SyncCtx is `SmtpClient`, which creates a new one if it is null via `AsyncronousManager`

Comment: Is the SyncCtx set by SmtpClient always unset, even when exceptions occur?

Comment: SmtpClient will replace a null SyncCtx with the default SyncCtx.  Turns out, `await` treats null and the default the same and ignores them both

Comment: The behavior you're observing is insane. Can you post a minimal repro?

Comment: I haven't gotten a repro case using just `Task.delay`. So far, it seems only if I do an async call using MysqlConnector.net.  I've searched that repo and I don't find any use of SynchronizationContext.

Comment: The last few paragraphs here seem to explain it.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/executioncontext-vs-synchronizationcontext/

Comment: @StephenCleary oh, damn, I've been reading your blogs on this trying to figure this out. 
Here are a couple fairly simple examples, both using MySqlConnector.net:
https://github.com/hunkydoryrepair/mysqlconnector1428
https://github.com/hunkydoryrepair/mysqlconnector1428b

Comment: it is occuring down at the network stream level, SslStream. If the stream is opened in one thread and then written to in another thread using `WriteAsync`. Hmmm